# Prepend/Append string for each element in a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have some code as below:

```
char[] separator = { ',' };

String[] idList = m_idsFromRequest.Split(separator);  //m_idsFromRequest="1,2....";
List<string> distinctIdList = idList.Distinct().ToList();
m_distinctIdList = distinctIdList.ToArray();
m_idsFromRequest = string.Join(" ", distinctIdList);
```

currently  m_idsFromRequest = ["1","2".........."] is as such.
I want to make it ["0|1","0|2".........."]    like append "0|" in each element . I wanted to know id I could do it without the foreach loop.

Comment: FYI your original code can be reduced to `m_idsFromRequest = string.Join(" ", m_idsFromRequest.Split(separator).Distinct());` and you'll avoid creating the unneeded intermediate list and array.

Comment: Also if your string has brackets at both ends then something like `["1","1"]` would not change as the distinct is being applied to values of `["1"` and `'"1"]`

Comment: sure I'll look into that. there is some in-between jugglery done with the intermediate data so I've just put up the overall stuff.  besides i ain't allowed to touch much code as per my seniors.

Comment: Note the answers below are assuming you're starting with a string like `1,2,3` and not a string like `["1","2","3"]` and would not work with the later values so the exact format of the initial string is important here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char[] separator = { ',' };
string m_idsFromRequest = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
String[] idList = m_idsFromRequest.Split(separator);  //m_idsFromRequest="1,2....";
List<string> distinctIdList = idList.Distinct().Select(t => "0|" + t).ToList();
m_idsFromRequest = string.Join(",", distinctIdList);
```

Just added the .Select() after .Distinct(). Inside the .Select you can transform each of the item in the list.

Apart from that i also added "," in your string.Join. Because you want it to be join by comma.

Comment: @Martin i have added the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Select` and `String.Join`:

```
var idsPrependedWithZero = m_idsFromRequest.Split(separator)
    .Distinct() // same as in your code
    .Select(id => $"0|{id}");
string result = string.Join(",", idsPrependedWithZero);
```

Comment: You forgot the `Distinct`

Comment: @juharr: where OP mentioned that they must be unique? Edit: I see. Fixed